# How can I analyze following circuit?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, amplifier, power-electronics

I have an electronic homework. I wonder how I can analyze and specify values of resistors and capacitors?

- 3 V < V<sub>out</sub> < 30 V
- Max I<sub>out</sub> = 3 A

Finally, what is the name of this circuit?

[image]

Comment: Well, there will be (approximately) a fixed voltage across R3 due to the Vbe of Q2. This also sets a current through R3 which is likely to mostly pass through R2 and R1. R2 can then set a varying voltage for the base of Q1 (emitter follower) and therefore set the output voltage. Some of R1's current will be sunk by Q2, the rest ensuring Q1's base current. So it's value will be somewhat more complicated to work out for any given circumstance. There are better design arrangements for a regulator.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. You've described this as a project but is this a homework/coursework question?

Comment: yes it is a homewrk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm leaving the determination of specs and component selection to someone else -- ideally, you  because no one will design the circuit for you. This section could even be off-topic.

I'll try my best to explain the circuit itself and Q2's function:

First, the transformer converts to 220Vac input to a (possibly) lower AC voltage. The rectifier (possibly a full bridge) will convert this AC to DC. And the filtering capacitor C1 filters out the ripple and brings a clean enough DC. Let's call this voltage \$V_{DC}\$. In an ideal world, this voltage should be equal to the peak of the transformer's output voltage.

Now let's ignore Q2 for a moment. I'm leaving it to the end.

The base of Q1 will see a voltage set by the divider resistors:

$$
\mathrm{
V_{B-Q1}=V_{DC}\cdot \frac{R_2+R_3}{R_1+R_2+R_3}
}
$$

If this voltage is high enough to turn the Q1 on then the emitter (output) voltage will be a diode-drop less than the base voltage. Remember that Q1 should have a resistor connected across it's emitter and GND or else no current will flow and no voltage will be developed at output.

Now let's look at Q2's function:

Q2 and the divider resistors seem to be forming an adjustable OVP: If the voltage across C1 is high enough to drop a diode-drop across R3 then Q2 will try to pull Q1's base to ground, therefore turn the Q1 off and disable the output.